# Testing rails' autocomplete with cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, cucumber

I need to test an autocomplete field with cucumber. How can I do that? I tried

```
  Scenario: Using Autocomplete   
  Given I am on the home page
  And there are the following users:
    |id |name   |
    |1  |foo    |
  When I fill in "name" with "f" 
  Then I should see "foo"
```

But then it fails because expected the following element's content to include "foo".
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a JS-enabled driver for your test. If you are using webrat o capybara you can try using selenium.

```
Then I should see "foo"
```

This doesn't work using the default web step because the DOM has not been updated when it looks for the text. There are 2 options:

**Option 1: Wait**

```
And I wait for 1 second
Then I should see "foo"
```

You need to implement this step to call sleep(n)

**Option 2: Custom locate**

Capybara's locate method will see if the target is present in the DOM. If not it will wait for a few seconds and try again and throw an error if it's still not present.

```
Then I should see the following autocomplete options:
| foo |
```

This is how the implementation of the steps looks like for me:

```
Then /^I should see the following autocomplete options:$/ do |table|
  table.raw.each do |row|
    locate(:xpath, "//a[text()='#{row[0]}']")
  end
end
```

If you need more detailed information on this subject I have written a blogpost with examples and some snippets, also dealing with clicking the autocomplete options presented:

http://www.aentos.com/blog/testing-ajax-autocomplete-fields-cucumber-and-capybara

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete uses Javascript to set the value of a text field ("name" in your case). Since Cucumber uses Webrat to inspect the response coming back from the server, and Webrat doesn't support Javascript, your scenario fails.

Cucumber can use [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) to automate Javascript testing and verify that the expected values are being plugged in. More info [here](http://wiki.github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/setting-up-selenium).